# The limit of supremums of sequences such that they converge to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Consider now for each $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$b_{k,n}=\dfrac 1k+ka_n-\left|\dfrac 1k-ka_n\right|$$

> Is it true $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}b_{k,n}=0?$$

If $k$ is fixed it is easy to see each $b_{k,n}$ converges to zero when $n\to\infty$. But does this suffice to say the above limit is also zero?

I checked it is true if for example $a_n=1/n$, but I don't know if it's true for every nonnegative sequence converging to zero.

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Just notice that somebody tried to make your life harder by writing a very simple function $2\min(a,b)$ as $a+b-|a-b|$.

Comment: @fedja thank you but still we would have the limit of $\sup_k\min\{1/k,ka_n\}$. How to show if this converges to zero?

Comment: Just think for a few minutes about what that supremum is for a fixed $a_n$. Only relax $k$ to positive reals to make life easier.

Comment: @fedja got it, thank you